# Shift of dirac delta function involving a sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, dirac-delta

Alright, I'm clueless on how to kickstart this question.

The idea of the dirac delta function by itself is understandable, at least at my current level. But once the question starts throwing in things like charge or a sphere, I get really lost.

Here's the question:

> $\int_{V}\vec{r}.\left ( \vec{d}-\vec{r} \right )\delta^{3}\left ( \vec{e}-\vec{r} \right )dV$ where $\vec{d}=\left \langle 1,2,3 \right \rangle ,\vec{e}=\left \langle 3,2,1 \right \rangle$, and V is a sphere of radius 1.5 centered at $\left ( 2,2,2 \right )$

I need to evaluate this integral.

$\delta^{3}\left ( \vec{e}-\vec{r} \right )$ tells me how much the dirac delta function is being shifted. In this case it is being shifted by $\vec{r}=\left \langle 2,2,2 \right \rangle$.

I can go no further. Help is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the integral with delta function means set a value, which is $$\int f(x)\delta (x-x_0)dx=f(x_0)$$ and in your case, it is $$\int \int \int _Vf(x,y,z)\delta (x-e_x)\delta (y-e_y)\delta (z-e_z)dxdydz$$ and is $\vec{e}\cdot (\vec{d}-\vec{e})$ when $\vec{e}$ in $V$ and $0$ when $\vec{e}$ is out of $V$. Hope it can help

Comment: Could you explain why $\vec{e}.(\vec{d}-\vec{e})$ holds when $\vec{e}$ is in V?

Comment: @Mathematicing It is easier consider 1D, assume $V$ means from a to b on x axis, then when $a<e_x<b$ $$\int _{-\infty}^a f(x)\delta (x-e_x)dx=\int _b^{\infty} f(x)\delta (x-e_x)dx=0$$ so $$\int _a^bf(x)\delta (x-e_x)dx=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta (x-e_x)dx=f(e_x)$$ In the case of 3D, when $$f(x,y,z)=x(d_x-x)+y(d_y-y)+z(d_z-z)$$ also have when $\vec{e}$ in $V$ $$\int\int\int _V f(x,y,z)\delta(x-e_x)\delta(y-e_y)\delta(z-e_z)dxdydz=\int\int\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}...dV=f(e_x,e_y,e_z)=e_x(d_x-e_x)+e_y(d_y-e_y)+e_z(d_z-e_z)= \vec {e} \cdot (\vec{d}-\vec{e})$$

Comment: I should have been more precise in my questioning. I understand the theorem in your post. I don't understand the significance of having the vector e to be in V.

Comment: @Mathematicing I think, when $\vec{e}$ is out of $V$, in the region of the integration, the delta function is always $0$, and $0$ multiply anything is still $0$, so it is $0$.